# populate a list dynamically in ant build script

Tags: ant

I have the following directory structure:

```
vardir1
vardir2
vardir3
vardir4
constantdir1
```

Inside constantdir1, i have an ant build script which takes the list of vardir1 to vardir4 and compiles them sequentially. The situation is, vardir1 to vardir4 may or may not exist all the time. Right now I have hard coded the values in the list and checking to see if the vardir is available before I kick off its compilation. Is there any way I can dynamically populate this list in my ant build script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the [subant](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/subant.html) task

```
<project name="demo" default="run">

    <target name="run">
        <subant>
            <fileset dir=".." includes="vardir*/build.xml"/>
        </subant>
    </target>

</project>
```

## Update

You can easily alter the criteria for the fileset, to include or exclude builds.

The following example excludes the calling **build.xml** file.

```
<project name="demo" default="run">

    <target name="run">
        <subant>
            <fileset dir=".." includes="**/build.xml" excludes="constantdir1/build.xml"/>
        </subant>
    </target>

</project>
```

Comment: The vardir1 to 4 is just an example. The actual dir names are totally different...W, X, Y , Z etc

Comment: @user1164061 answer updated to demonstrate how fileset is flexible enough to deal with any criteria